# Refreshing only the update with values from drop down box

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a drop down list named "DropDownList1". Any value picked from the drop down list must not refresh the page, but only refresh the panel My code is as follows.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px"  autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1sel">
     <asp:ListItem Text="abc" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="c" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When i run this code, it must call the function named "DropDownList1sel" in the ascx.cs where "Label1" is populated. Now the page is refreshed and the values are populated. I want to have the panel refreshed without the page being reloaded. Please help.

Comment: What code have you tried out ? Please edit your original question with the code.

Comment: show us some part of ascx.cs code

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to do

Set `UpdateMode=conditional` then add Trigger as DropDownList1

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="conditional" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers> 
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" 
       EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the DropDown inside your UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px" 
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="abc" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="c" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must place that panel inside an update panel..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <panel id="panel1">
      </panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```